# Data type transformation in Rust library

Tags: hash, implementation, random-oracle-model

I am using some ark libraries, such as ark_ff and ark_bls12_381, to implement some cryptographic algorithms. In these algorithms, random oracles are needed, which gets some group elements in G1,G2,Gt in bls curve, will output a scalar number(ark_bls12_381::Fr). How to do these steps? To be specific, I need to hash group elements and get an 'u8' array, and then generate a Fr from the bytes array. I need some help on the interfaces.

Comment: [This in-preparation RFC](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-irtf-cfrg-hash-to-curve-16.html) deals with hash-to-curve.